# Scrollbars in BorderLayout.PAGE_START / NORTH

Tags: java, swing, jscrollbar

Is there a way such that a component that is added to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` area will become scrollable if (and only if) there's not enough space?

I have attached a minimal example. If you resize the complete frame the label in the center will become scrollable, the label at the top won't.

Unfortunately, I can't change the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` positioning, as this is given by a framework. However I do have full control over the creation of `myComponent`.

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JComponent myComponent = new JScrollPane(new JLabel("<html>START-START<br><br>START-START</html>"));

    panel.add(myComponent, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(new JLabel("<html>CENTER-CENTER<br><br>CENTER-CENTER</html>")), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    final JFrame mainframe = new JFrame("Test");
    mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainframe.getContentPane().add(panel);

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      mainframe.pack();
      mainframe.setVisible(true);});
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way such that a component that is added to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START area will become scrollable if there's not enough space?

Yes there is. Make its preferred height less than its actual height. `BorderLayout` respects the preferred height of the component contained at PAGE_START, so it doesn't matter how many lines you put in your `JLabel`, it will be displayed at its preferred height – without scrollbars.

Try the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JComponent myComponent = new JScrollPane(new JLabel("<html>START-START<br><br>START-START</html>"));
    myComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

    panel.add(myComponent, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(new JLabel("<html>CENTER-CENTER<br><br>CENTER-CENTER</html>")),
            BorderLayout.CENTER);

    final JFrame mainframe = new JFrame("Test");
    mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainframe.getContentPane().add(panel);

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        mainframe.pack();
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

### EDIT

The below code doesn't give the best result but I think it is the way to go. You just need to play around with the different sizes of the different components.

I added a [ComponentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) to the content pane of the `JFrame`. When the `JFrame` is resized, you need to recalculate the heights of the top component and the center component according to your needs and then update the relevant component sizes. Note that the below code is not a complete solution but hopefully enough to allow you to arrive at a complete solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame mainframe = new JFrame("Test");
    JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("<html>START-START<br><br>START-START");
    JScrollPane topPane = new JScrollPane(topLabel);
    mainframe.add(topPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    JLabel centerLabel = new JLabel("<html>CENTER-CENTER<br><br>CENTER-CENTER");
    centerLabel.setMinimumSize(centerLabel.getPreferredSize());
    JPanel centerPane = new JPanel();
    centerPane.add(centerLabel);
    mainframe.add(centerPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        mainframe.pack();
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
        final Dimension centerPaneDim = centerPane.getPreferredSize();
        final Dimension topLabelDim = topLabel.getPreferredSize();
        mainframe.getContentPane().addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
            
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                Dimension size = e.getComponent().getSize();
                if (size.height < centerPaneDim.height + topLabelDim.height + 10) {
                    topPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(topLabelDim.width, 10 + size.height - centerPaneDim.height));
                }
                else {
                    topPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(topLabelDim.width, topLabelDim.height + 10));
                }
                e.getComponent().revalidate();
                e.getComponent().repaint();
            }
            
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
            
            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Then the component will always have scrollbars. I edited my question to be more precise: The initial layout should (more or less) match the initial layout from the minimal example. Only if then the size of the complete frame is reduced the page start should become scrollable (just like the center).

Comment: @Thomas `BorderLayout` doesn't work like that. Maybe a different [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) is appropriate. If not, then you can create your own. So you want the CENTER component **not** to scroll and only the PAGE_START component to scroll. Is that correct?

Comment: No, both components should become scrollable once their content isn't fully visible. (I don't care how the layout manager distributes the available space between center and page start, but once one of those components has less than their preferred size they should have scrollbars.) I was afraid that BorderLayout doesn't support that, but unfortunately I am bound to this structure. Anyway, thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: On the EDIT: Thanks! That's the behaviour I wanted (as you wrote it will need some fine tuning since in particular now the center doesn't become scrollable, but I will need to adjust it for my real world code anyway). In any case the idea with the ComponentListener is very helpful.